# Get-Childitem unknown "ReadError"

Tags: powershell

I need some help with solving one thing.

I have a script in place which collects logs from different folders. It was working well for a few months but today I found that it fails at GCI when reading some folder.

Here is the code.

```
Function Process-Logs {

  Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
     [string] $Area
  )

  $PathFailed  = "P:\IntegrationFileShare\failed\$Area"
  $PathLogs    = "P:\IntegrationFileShare\logs\$Area"
  
  #$Dest = "C:\tmp\SCRPT\"
  $Dest = 'C:\tmp\SCRPT\' +$Area + '\'
  
  $compress_log = @{
    Path             = $Dest + '*.log'
    CompressionLevel = "Fastest"
    DestinationPath  = ($Dest + "Logs_" + ($Area) + "_" + ($Date) + ".zip")
  }
  $compress_failed = @{
    Path             = $Dest + '*.log'
    CompressionLevel = "Fastest"
    DestinationPath  = ($Dest + "Failed_" + ($Area) + "_" + ($Date) + ".zip")
  }
  
  gci -path $PathLogs -filter *$Date* | %{cp $_.pspath -destination $Dest}
  if(Test-Path $compress_log.Path) {Compress-Archive @compress_log}
  Remove-Item -Path $Dest* -Include *.log
  
  gci -path $PathFailed -filter *$Date* | 
    %{cp $_.pspath -destination $Dest}
  if(Test-Path $compress_failed.Path) {Compress-Archive @compress_failed}
  Remove-Item -Path $Dest* -Include *.log

} #End Process-Logs

$Date = (get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
#$Date = "2021-03-28"
Process-Logs -Area "Europe"
Process-Logs -Area "LATAM"
Process-Logs -Area "APAC"
Upload-Files
```

For some reason, I got this error for LatAm all the time and Europe sometimes when I run full script.

```
gci : The specified server cannot perform the requested operation.
At C:\tmp\SCRPT\LogDownloader_PROD_Sched.ps1:25 char:3
+   gci -path $PathLogs -filter *$Date* | %{cp $_.pspath -destination $ ...
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (P:\IntegrationFileShare\logs\LATAM:String) [Get-ChildItem], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

When I removed -Recurse from GCI it started to work for Europe. That made me think that maybe there is a file or folder in depth which I cannot read as I am not an admin. But the same line of Code works for each Area and now it works for EU and APAC but fails all the time for LatAm.

When I go to this folder with Explorer I have not any problem and can move copy/move/delete files.
Also, I did Powershell->CD LatAm folder and did GCI with filter - it works.
When I run script operation by operation GCI works.

It fails only when I run the full script.
Can someone tell me what I'm missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a production script?!?

Comment: It's not a full script. It's a part which responsible for collecting logs. But Yes. Why?

Comment: Ты пробовал запустить сессию PS интерактивно и прошерстить файлы в папках? Ошибка вываливается также?

Comment: If you mean PS-Session so it's blocked. I wish I could use all the methods PS can give)

Answer (score 1):

Try out the command that's failing, and see where it fails at. `gci` should return one file at a time:

```
$Area = "LATAM"
$PathLogs    = "P:\IntegrationFileShare\logs\$Area"
gci -path $PathLogs -filter *$Date*
```

There are a handful of reasons you can get this specific error:

- The remote server needs a restart. Seriously.
- Your remote session is [running out of memory](https://www.manageengine.com/products/desktop-central/os-imaging-deployment/server-cannot-perform-requested-operation.html). Try doing smaller chunks and restarting your powershell in between.
- The remote server is using a different version of SMB (unlikely)
- You are getting [Remote SID compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/authorizaiton-issue-device-not-support-resource-sid-compression) errors against old devices (windows XP or older)

Comment: Actually, I tried that. 
I called ```Process-Logs -Area "LATAM"``` separately. I believe it's the same as what you mean.

With the other possible reasons you also may be right. Unfortunately, I'm so limited in right so I cannot even reboot this machine.
Thanks for reply.

Comment: @SergiiArkhangelskyi If you call just the `gci` command by itself without piping its output, it should output the files it *can* read up until where it fails. Or is it failing right at the beginning?

Comment: Hello,

I'm sorry for the delay. I finally used the isolated lines mentioned by you in a comment and it works(GCI without pipes).

In my case, the same function works for 6 locations under the same P:\IntegrationFileShare location and fails only for one folder.

¯\_(ツ)_/¯